# Magento 2 check customer is registered or not by using Id?

Tags: magento2, customer

Magento 2 how to check customer is registered or not by using Id?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Can you explain more details?

Comment: i want to check the customer is registered in magento by passing ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below

```
$customer_check = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer');
$customer_check->setWebsiteId($website_id);
$customer_check->load('CUSTOMER_ID');

if ( $customer_check->getId() ) {
      // the customer already exist
} else {
      // does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[EDIT]**

Should use `Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory`. Inject this class to construction.

```
    /** @var Customer $customer */
    $customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($customerId);
    if (!$customer->getId()) {
      ......
    }
```

---

Or can try
`\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface`

- `getById($customerId)`
- `get($email, $websiteId = null);`

And check:

```
   try {
        $customer = $customerRepository->getById(4);
    } catch (
        \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $noSuchEntityException
    ) {
        //Does not exist
    }
```